# How get jQuery UI Tabs DOM element by its index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

The goal of my experiment is to retrieve the DOM element ID by the index of the [jQuery UI's Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) element.

The `Tabs` control layout HTML begins as such:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab name 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab name 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

So say, if I want to write a JS function that would return `#tab3` for the tab with index 2, what jQuery method do I need to use to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector or [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to access elements by it's index in the matched set of elements.

```
$("#tabs ul li a:eq(2)").attr("href");
```

or

```
$("#tabs ul li a").eq(2).attr("href");
```

---

```js
alert($("#tabs ul li a:eq(2)").attr("href"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab name 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab name 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It can't be `attr("id")`. I don't have a single ID in there.

Comment: @c00000fd fixed... it'd be `href`, i misunderstood from *"retrieve the DOM element ID by the index"*...

Comment: Oops. My bad. Corrected the original question.